# Antd Menu does not revert back

Tags: css, reactjs, menu, antd, menuitem

I am using antd Layout in my react website.

When I resize window from large screen to smaller size then menu items are collapsed successfully but when I resize from smaller to larger size again then menu items are reverted back to its original size/position.

I am using menu from antd layout called `header-content-footer`

See [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xXQ5MyFINIEW1qLP8bjeYYHOAjiEZQTw/view?usp=sharing) for actual issue

Below is my code:

```
  <AntdLayout className={className}>
            <Header>
              <div className="flex items-center px-4 h-16">           
                    <Navigation mode="horizontal" theme="dark" />
              </div>
            </Header>
        <main
          className="flex flex-col container min-h-auto my-10 mx-auto px-5"
          style={fullWidth && { maxWidth: '90%', maxHeight: '90%' }}
        >
          <div>{children}</div>
        </main>
        {footer && (footer === true ? <Footer /> : footer)}
 </AntdLayout>
```

Below is my navigation file:

```
  <Menu
      className="select-none"
      theme={theme}
      defaultSelectedKeys={[router.asPath]}
      mode={mode}
    >
      {navigation.map(
        ({ title, icon, path, children, roles }, topLevelNavIndex) => {
          return <Menu.Item key={menuItem.path} icon={menuItem.icon}>
                        <Link href={menuItem.path}>{menuItem.title}</Link>
                 </Menu.Item>
        }
      )}
 </Menu>
```

Comment: can you share a mre? I am trying to reproduce the error from the [example](https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-top) from their website but without success

Comment: Sorry, not getting you. What is mre?

Comment: [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, have you solved this error? I'm in the exact situation and the solutions in the github issue does not work me. Thanks

Comment: @abcXYZ No, sadly I was not able to fix it. We changed the UI library from antd to mui because we were facing some other issues too.

Comment: @DrashtiKheni All good, thanks~